# setOnClickListener in adapter with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment

I just started learning Kotlin

i would like to start a new activitys from a RecyclerView with Kotlin.

for example :
if user tap on first item go to activity1
if user tap on secend item go to activity2
and...

i did make adaptor and adaptor will show in a feragment and there isnt any issue with start adaptor

my adaptor code:

```
package com.mysfk.android

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ReviewAdaptor() :RecyclerView.Adapter<ReviewAdaptor.ViewHolder>() {

    private var titles = arrayOf("بخاری","دریچه","فن و پد","آبیاری","فن چرخشی","مه پاش","پرده")
    private var details = arrayOf("جزیئات تست","جزیئات تست","جزیئات تست","جزیئات تست","جزیئات تست","جزیئات تست","جزیئات تست")
    private var images = intArrayOf(R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.icon)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ReviewAdaptor.ViewHolder {
        val v =LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_review,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ReviewAdaptor.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.tittleItem.text = titles[position]
        holder.ditealItem.text = details[position]
        holder.imageItem.setImageResource(images[position])

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return titles.size
    }
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var imageItem : ImageView
        var tittleItem : TextView
        var ditealItem :TextView
        init {
            imageItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageReview)
            tittleItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleReview)
            ditealItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detReview)

            itemView.setOnClickListener{

                }

            }
        }
}
```

and this is my items:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In ReviewAdaptor declare a listener:

```
private lateinit var itemClickListener: View.OnClickListener
public fun setItemClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener) {
    itemClickListener = listener
}
```

In your ViewHolder:

```
itemView.tag = this
itemView.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener)
```

And in your fragment:

```
reviewAdaptor.setItemClickListener{
    val viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder = it.tag as RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    // Open activity by postion
}
```

Comment: THANKS . i did all but i dont know how open activity by postion . tried sometnig but it didnt work . if you can please give me this code too.

Comment: "=this" - error expecting number declaration

Comment: itemView.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener) - expecting number declaration